# No connection to Internet and Scaling issue on Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am getting this error message while I am opening the anaconda-navigator from terminal in my machine X1 Carbon using Manjaro OS.

```
2021-06-29 18:13:39,886 - WARNING linux_scaling.get_scaling_factor_using_dbus:42
Can't detect system scaling factor settings for primary monitor.

libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /home/abbasmashaddy72/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /home/abbasmashaddy72/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
<urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
<urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
<urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
<urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
<urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
<urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

But I was able to open the anaconda navigator, but was not able to scale it to full screen:

Screen Resolution: 1920x1080

you can check the below Image link

[Image Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/154u-GMMC5l-Om2UGzUvHR-3x2bO-IUKy/view?usp=sharing)

I don't have the Nvidia or iris Graphics in my Laptop.

Below is the conda info for more details

```
active environment : base
    active env location : /home/abbasmashaddy72/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/abbasmashaddy72/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/abbasmashaddy72/.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.1
    conda-build version : 3.21.4
         python version : 3.8.10.final.0
       virtual packages : __linux=5.4.124=0
                          __glibc=2.33=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/abbasmashaddy72/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/abbasmashaddy72/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/abbasmashaddy72/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/abbasmashaddy72/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/abbasmashaddy72/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/abbasmashaddy72/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.1 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.8.10 Linux/5.4.124-1-MANJARO manjaro/21.0.7 glibc/2.33
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Looks like your graphics drivers were built with GCC 11, but the `libstdc++.so.6` from Conda only supports up to GCC 9. Did you manually build the drivers?

Comment: No, I had built any driver manually. I am using Manjaro Arch Linux

Comment: Okay. Manjaro was probably just ahead of the curve. Conda Forge started offering `libstdcxx-ng=11` builds around the beginning of August, so you shouldn't have this issue any more.

Comment: Oh wait - just realized you installed Anaconda, which hasn't dropped a release since May and isn't building a `libstdcxx-ng=11`. So, you'd be okay to install [a Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) (I recommend Mambaforge), but Anaconda/Miniconda may still be incompatible.